# using() vs local scope object in C#

Tags: c#, scope, garbage-collection, using

Consider the following example.

```
public void SomeMethod(){
 using(var sqlConnection= new SQLConnection()){
 //some code here
 }
}
```

In the above example the sqlConnection outside the using block will be disposed and garbage collected

```
public void SomeMethod(){
var sqlConnection = new SQLConnection(){
}
}
```

In this example the `sqlConnection` object will be garbage collected after the execution of `SomeMethod()`.

The question here is, is it really necessary to use a `using()` scope in this case as it is ok for me to have the object garbage collected at the end of execution. Could some one share your thoughts here.

Comment: Just an observation, the `sqlConnection` will be garbage collected *at some point* after the method execution. The `using` statement makes sure that the `Dispose` method of that object will be called deterministically rather than waiting for GC execution to dispose and collect it.

Comment: `object will be garbage collected after` **after** is not the same as **immediately after**. Technically I die after I was born. **But how long after?**

Answer (score 3):

`IDisposable` has nothing in common with garbage collection. It is just **a contract** saying that you should call `Dispose` on an object implementing it because it needs to make some cleanup. `using` statement is a helping tool that just makes that for you. Moreover, various tools (i.e. Resharper) may notice that you are not calling `Dispose` (or use `using`) on such *Disposable* object.

Garbage collection is just the other mechanism that will reclaim memory after no longer needed objects. In your case, `SQLConnection` will be garbage collected after some time the method exits (because it will notice that nothing is referencing it anymore).

Comment: If i could downvote my own answer i would, as such ill upvote yours

Comment: @MichaelRandall haha, if only I could upvote deleted answers;)

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is: of course it's **preferable** and **recommended** to use `using` with `IDisposable` object because it ensures some expected behavior, but the **necessity** of using may depend on other factors such as: correct implementation of `IDisposable` pattern and absence of need to reclaim the resources immediately (maybe because they will be reclaimed shortly anyway in short-term console application or because of any other reason known only for you). But considering fact that in vast majority of cases these factors are unknown we prefer to take precautions by applying `using` always where it's possible.

To be more specific the correctly implemented `IDisposable` pattern ensures that unmanaged resources (which `IDisposable` is about) are released either during explicit `Dispose` call (that is when an object leaves `using` scope) or during finalization phase (that is when an object is collected by GC). In your case `SQLConnection` type has correct `IDisposable` implementation so applying or not applying `using` in this specific case is almost identical. Almost - because you still cannot be sure when GC starts collecting your object and you cannot handle the situation when `Dispose` throws an exception. That's why the recommendation and the best practice is to use `using` anyway but your question was about necessity in your specific case so basing on the invormation above - you decide.